# Laravel Spark work flow and customization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-spark

This may be a simple question for people that are using Spark.

I was working off of files in the 'vendor' folder and it seems I should not be editing files there but when I modify files in the 'resources' folder and refresh the browser nothing happens. So obviously it's using the files in the 'vendor' folder.

What is the right work flow if I'm supposed to edit the files in the 'resources' folder?

Comment: You never should edit files in `vendor` directory. What files exactly are you trying to modify?

Comment: Just basic stuff like routes and navigation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to edit views, you should run `php artisan vendor:publish` command which will copy all views allowed to edit to `resources/views` directory.

https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-laravel-spark-a-deep-dive#views

Comment: Ah, interesting. So if I do vendor:publish I can edit the corresponding files in the 'resources' folder? How about the routes, controllers, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for providing some knowledge though.

Comment: I was looking through https://github.com/daem0ndev/laravel-spark/blob/master/app/Providers/SparkServiceProvider.php
Do you think I just add a path to the defineRoutes() function for the routes?